# Select statement with dynamic columns where these columns are rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to write a select statement that with some fixed columns and dynamic columns.
here Dynamic Columns names are the rows in another table.

I have tried this but getting error. Please tell me where my error is

```
set @sql=(Select subject from tbl_subjects where C_Id=22);
SELECT 
    ta.rollno,
    ta.StdNm,
    tc.C_Name,
    @sql
FROM
    tbl_cmarks tm,
    tbl_admission ta,
    tbl_classes tc
WHERE
    tm.Cid = tc.C_Id
        AND ta.rollno = tm.rollno
        AND tm.Cid = 22 and tm.Examid=9
```

Mysql showing:

> *Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row*

Could any one tell me how to do this in mysql?

Comment: When you run the query `Select subject from tbl_subjects where C_Id=22` how many rows are returned?  Are they identical values?  Can you edit your post with some sample data and the desire result?

Comment: Thank you  @bluefeet for early response. Select subject from tbl_subjects where C_Id=22 will return 7 subject names

Comment: that 7 subject names are column names in tbl_cmarks. I want to select records from tbl_camrks, but don't know how many columns to pass in select statement, thats why i am selecting the rows from subjects table identical to class 22

Comment: If you have the column name in `tbl_cmarks` as different subjects, it sounds like you have a design flaw.  Can you edit you original question with the table structures, sample data and then the desired result?  Or even better create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your table details.

Comment: Plz look at this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59ec8/3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59ec8/8 look at this i have modified the code but no result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at your table structures, I would suggest that you change the design to something that is normalized. For example:

```
create table tbl_subjects
(
  sub_id int,
  subject_name varchar(25)
);

create table tbl_cmarks
(
  c_id int,
  examid int,
  rollno int,
  sub_id int,
  mark int
);
```

Using something similar to above will allow you to add new subjects without having to alter your table.  Then you will just join the tables on the `sub_id` to get the list of subjects for each class.

```
select ta.rollno,ta.StdNm,tc.C_Name,
  tm.mark,
  s.subject
FROM tbl_cmarks tm
INNER JOIN tbl_classes tc
  ON tm.Cid = tc.C_Id
INNER JOIN tbl_admission ta
  ON ta.rollno = tm.rollno
INNER JOIN tbl_subjects s
  on tm.sub_id = s.sub_id
where tm.Cid = 22 
  and tm.Examid=9;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa20f/3). The above will give you a result in rows, but you could easily apply an aggregate function with a CASE expression to pivot the data into columns. Similar to the following:

```
select ta.rollno,
  ta.StdNm,
  tc.C_Name,
  max(case when s.subject = 'English' then tm.mark end) Emglish,
  max(case when s.subject = 'Physics' then tm.mark end) Physics
FROM tbl_cmarks tm
INNER JOIN tbl_classes tc
  ON tm.Cid = tc.C_Id
INNER JOIN tbl_admission ta
  ON ta.rollno = tm.rollno
INNER JOIN tbl_subjects s
  on tm.sub_id = s.sub_id
where tm.Cid = 22 
  and tm.Examid=9
group by  ta.rollno, ta.StdNm, tc.C_Name;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa20f/4).

But if you don't change your current table structure and if you don't know the columns that you are going to return, then you will have to implement a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL.

First, you will create the list of the classes:

```
set @sqlList = null;
set @query = null;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(concat('tm.', subject)) 
INTO @sqlList
FROM tbl_subjects
where C_Id=22;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/781d7/5). This will give you the list of classes for each `c_id`. Once you have the list of classes, then you can add this to the rest of the sql string so the full code will be:

```
set @sqlList = null;
set @query = null;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(concat('tm.', subject)) 
INTO @sqlList
FROM tbl_subjects
where C_Id=22;

SET @query 
  = CONCAT('SELECT ta.rollno,ta.StdNm,tc.C_Name, ', @sqlList, ' 
            FROM tbl_cmarks tm
            INNER JOIN tbl_classes tc
              ON tm.Cid = tc.C_Id
            INNER JOIN tbl_admission ta
              ON ta.rollno = tm.rollno
            where tm.Cid = 22 
              and tm.Examid=9');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/781d7/4)

Comment: All this and no information_schema involvement? Wow !!! This is worth a +2, but you'll have to settle for +1 !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Thanks! I also edited my answer to suggest a table redesign, IMO the `tbl_cmarks` is poorly design and the OP will have a much easier time if they redesign the table.

Comment: Thank you @bluefeet. If i create the table structure like as you mentioned above i have a problem i.e., suppose student in Class 22 means XA having 7 subjects, here i need to add 7 records only identical field is sub_id, if  class XA have 60 students 60*7 records for 1 single Exam_Id, if Exams are 6 for XA 60*7 records for also 6 times need to capture in table.So the table will have more data with repeated row values. thats y i have taken the structure like i was mentioned, here Subject Names will be max 9 identical for all classes from 1-10th.

Comment: BTW, for *querying* a large table, might want ` LIMIT nnn` at end of @query. I was doing something like this via phpmyadmin to an AWS DB, and it seemed to be hanging. I finally realized w/o `LIMIT` I was asking it to send ALL the rows to phpmyadmin to be formatted for display.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command `set @sql=(Select subject from tbl_subjects where C_Id=22);` gives you an error because subquery returns more than 1 row. You either need to use cursors, and iterate through resultset or do something like

```
set @sql=(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
 from tbl_subjects where C_Id=22);
```